# Serialize dates in a 'range' format without using a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to find ranges of dates within a column and serialize them in a concise format (`start` - `end` for a range or `date` for a single-date range).

I have a CTE (`readings`) that returns a data set that resembles:

```
ID          VALUE   DATE
1234567     A       2012-05-09
1234567     A       2012-05-10
1234567     A       2012-05-11
1234567     A       2012-05-16
1234567     A       2012-05-17
1234567     A       2012-05-20
1234567     B       2012-05-11
1234567     B       2012-05-12
1234567     B       2012-05-13
1234567     B       2012-05-14
```

I've been able to get:

```
ID          VALUE   TOTAL_DAYS  DATES
1234567     A       6           2012-05-09; 2012-05-10; 2012-05-11; 2012-05-16; 2012-05-17; 2012-05-20
1234567     B       4           2012-05-11; 2012-05-12; 2012-05-13; 2012-05-14
```

Using:

```
readings AS (
...
)
,
reading_aggr AS (

    SELECT  ID, [VALUE]
            ,count(distinct date) TOTAL_DAYS
            ,STUFF((
                SELECT '; ' + cast(date as varchar)
                FROM    readings r0
                WHERE   id=r0.id
                    AND value=r0.value
                ORDER BY date
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'
            ),1,2,'') AS DATES
    FROM    readings
    GROUP BY id, [value]
)

SELECT * FROM readings_aggr
```

I would like to format it as such:

```
ID          VALUE   TOTAL_DAYS  DATES
1234567     A       6           2012-05-09 - 2012-05-11; 2012-05-16 - 2012-05-17; 2012-05-20
1234567     B       4           2012-05-11 - 2012-05-14
```

Is this possible without using a procedural approach?

Comment: Your query is not using a procedure so I have no idea what the question really is.

Comment: I didn't want someone to post a solution that re-architects the query as a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
 SELECT ID, VALUE, MIN([DATE]) AS startDate, MAX([DATE]) AS endDate
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, VALUE, DATE, 
             DATEDIFF(Day, '1900-01-01' , [DATE])- ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID, VALUE ORDER BY [DATE] ) AS DateGroup
      FROM readings ) rGroups
   GROUP BY ID, VALUE, DateGroup
```

to get a table expression containing all start - end intervals of you data:

```
ID      VALUE   startDate   endDate
--------------------------------------
1234567 A       2012-05-09  2012-05-11
1234567 A       2012-05-16  2012-05-17
1234567 A       2012-05-20  2012-05-20
1234567 B       2012-05-11  2012-05-14
```

Then use the above query within `reading_aggr`:

```
;WITH start_end_readings AS (
   SELECT ID, VALUE, MIN([DATE]) AS startDate, MAX([DATE]) AS endDate
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, VALUE, DATE, DATEDIFF(Day, '1900-01-01' , [DATE])- ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID, VALUE ORDER BY [DATE] ) AS DateGroup
      FROM readings ) rGroups
   GROUP BY ID, VALUE, DateGroup
), readings_aggr AS (

    SELECT  ID, [VALUE]
            ,count(distinct date) TOTAL_DAYS 
            ,STUFF((
                SELECT '; ' + cast(startDate as varchar) + 
                       CASE WHEN startDate <> endDate THEN ' - ' + cast(endDate as varchar)
                            ELSE ''
                       END
                FROM    start_end_readings r0
                WHERE   r1.id=r0.id AND r1.value=r0.value
                ORDER BY startDate 
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'
            ),1,2,'') AS DATES
    FROM    readings AS r1
    GROUP BY id, [value]
)
SELECT * FROM readings_aggr
```

to get the desired result:

```
ID      VALUE   TOTAL_DAYS  DATES
===========================================================================
1234567 A       6           2012-05-09 - 2012-05-11; 2012-05-16 - 2012-05-17; 2012-05-20
1234567 B       4           2012-05-11 - 2012-05-14
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf364/1)

Comment: Having run into yet-another-string-aggregation requirement, I finally gave up and tried SQLCLR. Takes a lot less to call and is easier to optimize if you have covering indexes, especially if you need to aggregate multiple fields

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: do you have an example of this?

Comment: The answer by @jlee-tesik points to an [example from MSDN ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165055%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). That's only the string aggregation part though, you still have to create the query that calculates the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be able to do this using a CLR aggregate.

Here's an example from MSDN which concatenates your data together. Just by changing the comma to a semi-colon, you could have your current format with a much cleaner query.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165055%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Once that's in place, you can tweak the Accumulate and/or Terminate method to look over the data and output ranges where possible. You'd probably want to accumulate the values into something like a SortedList instead of a StringBuilder, and then do the range analysis in the Terminate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, V CHAR(1), D DATE )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1234567, 'A', '2012-05-09' ),
        ( 1234567, 'A', '2012-05-10' ),
        ( 1234567, 'A', '2012-05-11' ),
        ( 1234567, 'A', '2012-05-16' ),
        ( 1234567, 'A', '2012-05-17' ),
        ( 1234567, 'A', '2012-05-20' ),
        ( 1234567, 'B', '2012-05-11' ),
        ( 1234567, 'B', '2012-05-12' ),
        ( 1234567, 'B', '2012-05-13' ),
        ( 1234567, 'B', '2012-05-14' );

WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        V ,
                        CASE WHEN MIN(D) <> MAX(D)
                             THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MIN(D), 121) + ' - '
                                  + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MAX(D), 121)
                             ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MIN(D), 121)
                        END AS D ,
                        COUNT(*) AS cn
               FROM     ( SELECT    ID ,
                                    V ,
                                    D ,
                                    DATEADD(dd,
                                            -ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY V ORDER BY D ),
                                            D) AS rn
                          FROM      @t
                        ) a
               GROUP BY ID ,
                        V ,
                        rn
             ),-- SELECT * FROM cte1,
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        V ,
                        SUM(cn) TOTAL_DAYS ,
                        STUFF((SELECT   '; ' + D
                               FROM     cte1 r0
                               WHERE    cte1.id = r0.id
                                        AND cte1.V = r0.V
                        FOR   XML PATH('') ,
                                  TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
                              1, 2, '') AS DATES
               FROM     cte1
               GROUP BY id ,
                        V
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte2
```

Output:

```
ID      V   TOTAL_DAYS  DATES
1234567 A   6           2012-05-09 - 2012-05-11; 2012-05-16 - 2012-05-17; 2012-05-20
1234567 B   4           2012-05-11 - 2012-05-14
```

The idea is firstly get islands(https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) and then apply your stuff. I know @Betsos outruned me, but this is a little different. But the idea is the same.